# Break line in input placeholder

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, form-submit

I've put a contact form within a modal.

However, when entering message in the message-part the text won't break line afte a while but instead go on forever to the right. This makes it hard for the writer of the message to see all that is written before submitting. I need help changing this. 
It's the "Meddelande" (means message) part that needs this fix only.

Here is a print screen, (the text is in swedish but it illustrates my point). 
[messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHe3c.png)

Here is my code and would love to get some help. 
Please ask if I'm not clear enough as I might have missed some important information :)

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Kontakt</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="TelNummer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Telefonnummer</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="TelNummer" placeholder="Ange telefonnummer">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="EMail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EMail" placeholder="Ange email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Meddelande"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Meddelande</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="height:50px" id="Meddelande" placeholder="Ange meddelande">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" onclick="SkickaMail()">
                            Skicka
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>



                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Avbryt
                    </button>
                    @*<p>Need <a href="#">help?</a></p>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Change it t a `<textarea>` if you want multiple lines

Comment: For this use `textarea` not use `input`.